# weblogic ssl cacerts issue

Tags: security, ssl, weblogic, jks

We have a requirement where we have my.crt file which we want to use it with cacerts.

- I have checked the blogs and documentation its not clear on how to use my.crt file with cacerts
- I have used `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAkeystore='/xxx/sr/cacerts'` to change the path of the keystore , but cannot see it loading in the logs

Also when creating identity.jks and trust.jks from cacerts file I am getting :

```
keytool -importcert -alias mykey -trustcacerts -file trust.jks -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Also should I be using custom identity custom trust OR custom identity and command-line trust to get this working

Comment: It sounds like you have lots of questions and do not understand cert generation... Here is how to do what you're asking: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you are giving wrong values to keytool command....

if you want to import your .crt file to cacerts then you must have to specify in keytool command but you are specifying trust.jks here....

Wrong:

keytool -importcert -alias mykey -trustcacerts -file trust.jks -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit

Correct: Use the below command.It must have to work

keytool -importcert -alias mykey -trustcacerts -file **filename.crt** -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit